# Adding custom column to Eloquent query result (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, foreach, eloquent

I get a collection from my database with

```
$events = DB::table('events')
  ->select('id', 'eventId', 'resourceId', 'title', 'start', 'end')
  ->get();
```

and want to add a field `color` so that I can set the color value depending on the value of the field `title`. My approach does not work, the `echo` and `put` gives an error.

```
$events->put('color', 'blue');
$events->each(function($item, $key){
  if($item == 'Garage')
    echo $item;
});
```

Comment: That's the [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#introduction), not [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent). If you'd use Eloquent you could create an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

Comment: This is not an eloquent query, but a query using the query builder. If it was an eloquent query you would work directly with an Event model and you could add `color` to the `visible` array and define a `getColorAttribute` function on the model: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor  What words 5 do you see?

Comment: I understand that I can use Accessors to access columns that already exist. But I also need to add the column `color` to the collection which does not exist in the database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First use an `Eloquent` approach.

```
$events = Event::query()
    ->select('id', 'eventId', 'resourceId', 'title', 'start', 'end')
    ->get();
```

On your Event model, add an Eloquent [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators).

```
class Event extends Model
{
    public function getColorAttribute($value)
    {
        if ($this->title === 'Garage') {
            return 'blue';
        }

        return 'unknown';
    }
}
```

Now you can append this for transformation or access it directly.

```
class Event extends Model
{
     protected $appends = ['color'];
}

$event->color;
```

Comment: Thank you, I really learned a lot from this example.